# Resource files synchronization failed due to service error

Tags: publishing-service, items-as-resources

In Sitecore 10.2 we're seeing the following errors in the publishing logs (**App_Data\logs\Publishing.log.20230220.113941.txt**):

```
10820 11:39:52 INFO  Started synchronizing resource files with Publishing Service. Publishing operations will paused temporary while synchronizing
10820 11:39:57 WARN  Resource files synchronization failed due to service error. Operation will be retried in 5 minutes
Exception: Sitecore.Publishing.Service.ResourceFiles.Exceptions.ResourceFilesServiceException
Message: Api error
Source: Sitecore.Publishing.Service
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.RemoteProxies.ResourceFilesServiceRemoteProxy.<ExecuteAsync>d__13`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.RemoteProxies.ResourceFilesServiceRemoteProxy.<UploadAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.RemoteProxies.ResourceFilesServiceRemoteProxy.<InstallFileAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.ResourceFiles.ResourceFilesUploader.<UploadFileAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.ResourceFiles.ResourceFilesUploader.<UploadAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.ResourceFiles.ResourceFilesSynchronizationManager.<TryUpload>d__34.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: Refit.ApiException
Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 413 (Request Entity Too Large).
Source: Refit
```

This error appears to be why this message continuously appears:

[image: Error Message]

- The publishing service logs do not indicate any of the scheduled tasks are running.
- We have custom IAR files where the largest file is 89 MB.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past the error by doing the following:

- Increase the `maxAllowedContentLength` in the **web.config** for Sitecore Publishing Service.
- Restart SPS and then Sitecore XM.

The following is the complete **web.config** for SPS. I added the `<security>` section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Host settings can be configured by overriding the default settings provided in sitecorehost.xml. 
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```